# How to join table conditional column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following two tables :

**user_profile**

```
id | name  | email       | phone
1  | Rahul |r@gmail.com  |1234567890
2  | Rohan |r1@gmail.com |1234567890
3  | Mohan |m@gmail.com  |1234567890
```

**user_request_table**

```
    id | from_user_id|to_user_id|status
    1  |      1      |   2      | 2 
    2  |      3      |   1      | 2
```

Here status

> 0 = Request is cancel,
> 1 = request is pending,
> 2 = request accepted

So request accepted(status=2) means they both are friends.

Now suppose I am login with user id 1 (Rahul) **I need to display rahul's friend with user_profile data. What should be the query so it display Rohan's and Mohan's profile data.**

Comment: Add `and status=2` to the ON clause of your join.

Comment: with which column I should join ? from_user or to_user ? it should be differet in all records.

Answer (score 1):

You should join the tables like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM user_profile p INNER JOIN user_request_table r
ON (p.id, ?) IN ((r.from_user_id, r.to_user_id), (r.to_user_id, r.from_user_id))
WHERE r.status = 2;
```

Change `?` to the `id` of the user that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aaa80deb6893ce700ed730faaf1f7372).

Comment: can you explain IN statement in join ?

Comment: @DavidCoder the id of the user that you want to query may exist either in the column from_user_id or in the column to_user_id, so the ON clause could be written like: `ON (p.id = r.from_user_id AND ? = r.to_user_id) OR (p.id = r.to_user_id AND ? = r.from_user_id)` or with IN. I prefer the operator IN because you only need to write the parameter of the user's id only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U2.ID,U2.NAME,U2.EMAIL,U2.PHONE
FROM USER_PROFILE AS U
JOIN REQUEST AS R ON U.ID=R.FROM_USER_ID
JOIN USER_PROFILE AS U2 ON R.TO_USER_ID=U2.ID
 WHERE R.STATUS=2 AND R.FROM_USER_ID=1
   UNION ALL
SELECT U2.ID,U2.NAME,U2.EMAIL,U2.PHONE
FROM USER_PROFILE AS U
JOIN REQUEST AS R ON U.ID=R.TO_USER_ID
JOIN USER_PROFILE AS U2 ON R.FROM_USER_ID=U2.ID
WHERE R.STATUS=2 AND R.TO_USER_ID=1
```

Could you please try this query if it is suitable for you